# The right part is lost when using ghostscript to convert .prn file to pdf

Tags: ghostscript

I am using ghostpcl-9.20-win32.
I have tried this:
`gpcl6win32 -dNOPAUSE-dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.prn`

The right part of the input file is lost in the output.

input file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B29492qqMUX7Zk9nUmhDYXpJRVk
output file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29492qqMUX7T2RxVDZJaE9seEE

Answer (score 0):

Your PCL file (actually it appears to be simple text, not even PCL) doesn't contain a media request.

In the absence of a media size, GhostPCL (NB **NOT** Ghostscript, GhostPCL) uses its default media size. Depending on a number of factors that will be either A4 or US Letter, portrait.

If you want different media, then you need to tell GhostPCL what you want. You need to use `-sPAPERSIZE` or `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS -dDEVICEHIGHTPOINTS` or any of the other media selection switches.